# meaning of "maybe she did see"

Tags: grammar, expressions, phrase-meaning

what is the difference between:

> maybe she did see

and

> maybe she saw

is it a grammatical usage of maybe?

Comment: Regarding your first question, see [emphatic do](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=emphatic+do)

Comment: It would be better if you gave complete sentences as examples. 'Maybe', like 'perhaps', can be used to start a sentence, but only makes sense where there is (usually prior) context. "Maybe she saw  a mirage" is unmarked, offering an explanation perhaps. "Maybe she _did_ see  a mirage" (with stress on 'did') is a marked variant, a concessive to 'her' / corrective to the person spoken to ("... perhaps we should give her the benefit of the doubt").

Comment: This Q may be asked on [ell.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's a pragmatic difference.

Auxiliary "do/does/did" in a declarative sentence (i.e. not a question and not negative) is emphatic, often contrastive.

So "Maybe she saw" is neutral; "Maybe she did see" is emphatic, or contrastive. The precise connotation depends on the context, but probably somebody had suggested, or the speaker has been thinking, that she did not see, and is now considering, as a new idea, the possibility that she did.