# Meaning of "We have worked too long for the priests to undermine us with more fairy-tales."

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

I want to know the real meaning of this sentence:

> We have worked too long for the priests to undermine us with more fairy-tales.

Have we worked too long for the priests?

Or have we worked too long to be undermined by the priests?

The context is that this is a sentence of a story. The person who say it is a politician and I want to know what he means by this sentence. He is angry while saying this. He says "We have worked too long for the priests", then says "to undermine us with more fairy-tales."

I can't understand the relation of the first part with the second part. Is this some a kind of protest? Is he saying that the government worked for priests but they undermine the government with religious beliefs (that the speaker calls fairy-tales)?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't capitalize the pronoun i? (You need to fix all of them in this question and your previous two questions) I believe you are the one who wrote the sentence and you have to let us know what you want to mean using this sentence. When do priests undermine you with more fairy-tales? In what context?

Comment: Did you ask the same question on ELL and deleted it and posted here again? Is there any reason to do that? http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83379/we-have-worked-too-long-for-the-priests-to-undermine-us-with-more-fairy-tales

Comment: ps. those comments by @Rathony ARE quibbles. Perhaps that knowledge will help guide your future understanding of the term.

Comment: Quibble = "a slight objection or criticism"
Pointing out the "question doesn't make sense" is a slight objection. Taking it further would be argumentation, or possibly indignation... but you didn't. The recommendations toward what needs to be fixed are small criticisms. Major Criticisms might include red penning the entire thing. The notes on "you're doing it weird" are in the same zone.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is it to determine the meaning of the sentence? Or to determine if the meaning of the sentence is mostly a quibble? Or are you wondering by "is it a quibble" whether asking for the meaning of that statement is a quibble?

Comment: @Rathony why are you so rough? i add explanation to my question. i deleted my question in ell.stackexchange because there was no answer there. so i asked it here. anyway try to be kinder :)

Comment: @Mitch I add explanation to my question, hope it helps answering my question. Thanks for your attention and not being rough like others :)

Comment: I don't think you understand how Stack Exchange works. You should not move around your question just because there was no answer. You should have waited on English Language Learners. If there is no answer, edit your question which will move your question to the top of the front page. Do not do this again. If you are speakers of other languages learning English, you should post your question on ELL.

Comment: Look at the last comment by Kris. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311067/meaning-of-maybe-she-did-see

Comment: @Rathony OK! next time I'll be wating for you to answer my question there

Comment: @VvVv a 'quibble' is a disagreement over a very small usually tangential point. So I don't think you mean to use that word. Also, I think the true direction of the sentence depends on the literal surrounding context. Can you give the few sentences leading up to it? That will help us parse what refers to what positively or negatively. It may very well turn out that the sentence is poorly written (ambiguous).

Comment: I can suggest two rewordings that are what I think are intended by the author. "We have worked too long to be undermined by the priests with more fairy-tales." or "We have worked too long to allow the priests to have us undermined with more fairy-tales."

Answer (score 4):

Is it a quibble? No.

It's hard to deduce a precise meaning without some context.  The use of "fairy tales" implies that the writer does not believe in the teachings of the priests and considers them to be nothing better than stories for children.

So the sentence can be read as "We have worked hard, but our efforts are being undermined by the false teachings of priests".

Comment: thanks for your answer, the speaker says "we have working hard for the priests" what does it mean? i can't understand the connection between first part and second part of the sentece.

Comment: @VvVv The sentence is a bit ambiguous.  But I don't read it as working *for* the priests.  Hence the comma in my version above.

Comment: @VvVv You're breaking the sentence in the wrong place. Read it as "We have worked too long, for the priests to undermine us with more fairy-tales", or, "We have worked too long [for it to be acceptable that] the priests undermine us with more fairy-tales", or reversing it, "It's not right that the priests undermine us with more fairy-tales, after we have worked for so long"

Comment: @user568458 are you sure? It is weired and not match to the sense of speaker (anger)

Comment: @VvVv yes, definitely, especially if the speaker is angry. This sort of phrase, "We've done too much X to not keep doing X until we win", is something people often say in determination, or in stubborn or angry defiance. Real life example: ["We've come too far to turn back now. We've come too far to let our hearts grow faint. Now is the time to keep pushing forward" - Barrack Obama](https://www.facebook.com/barackobama/photos/a.53081056748.66806.6815841748/10151244813911749/?type=1&theater)

Comment: @VvVv  It's not "worked too hard" as in "we should have worked less", it's more like "we've worked so hard on X that giving up is not an option". I'm guessing your politician in the story goes on to call for some sort of fight-back against the priests? Here's another real-life example: ["We’ve worked too hard to let the extreme ideology of Bill O’Brien stop the progress we’ve made. We’ve stood up and stopped him before and we’re going to have to do it again in 2016"](http://granitegrok.com/blog/2014/11/nh-democrats-grubering-supporters-lies-bill-obrien) - anger and defiance

Comment: @user568458 thanks a lot. I think I understand.